# How to force function to be called within constructor?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++98

We have a shared library that we need to make thread safe and we found that only thing that are causing problem is one thread safe singleton class in which we have  stuff like below code :

```
int getLocationID(string name)
{
      if(LocationMap.empty())
      {
         populateLocationMap();  
      }
      return LocationMap[name];
}
```

So issue is when two client threads call this getLocationID function simultaneously and both found it to be empty then during populateLocationMap in which we are reading from some file and inserting locationID and locationName in map and during this parallel insertion our library is crashing and we don't want to put mutex here as it will affect parallelism and populate function will be called once.Now since this is thread safe singleton so we thought of putting all these populateFunction in constructor and that is meeting our functional requirement also but the problem is if we have some future enhancement **how we can ensure that private function of class only be called in constructor** ?

Comment: Uhh... Call it in the constructor, and put a big nasty comment, in that function, stating in no uncertain terms that it's only called from the constructor?

Comment: ok so there is no way we can force via language features

Comment: I don't think that there is any language feature that allows you to mark methods as "run only once". If you really wanted to you could add some flags that are used to check whether the method was already called or not. But I do not think that's a good idea.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once

Comment: Aside: there are direct solutions to the "only do initialization once" problem.

Comment: Does doing the initialization on construction rather than first use actually adhere to your design? My initial assumption would be that you wouldn't have bothered to do the whole "don't initialize the object on creation but initialize its parts on first usage" pattern unless you actually needed to delay that initialization.

Comment: @Hurkyl but its first usage can be parallel and that is causing whole problem and i don't want to put mutex there and double check locking in itself will make things complex as I am using ACE_Singleton and problems can be avoided in constructor itself but i just want to ensure that if in future we have enhancements like this any other developer should put this populate like stuff in constructor only

Comment: @Kapil: If you actually have a real need for population to be delayed until first use, then making the population happen on construction should be your *last* resort for solving the problem.

Comment: @Kapil: Also, IIRC, the mutex would only ever matter when a thread detects that population may need to occur, so I'm not sure why you're so adverse to it.

Comment: @David we are still using c++98

Comment: How about defining a base class and making `populateLocationMap` a private method of it? Then you can call the method in the constructor of the base class.

Comment: Yes I can call private function in constructor but i want to force other developer if required to write private function then they can only call in constructor

Answer (score 2):

> how we can ensure that private function of class only be called in
>   constructor ?

The solution I have seen used in bigger embedded system developments ... call the constructor in the 'main' thread *before* any other threads are running.  This presumes that "LocationMap.empty()" works correctly from all threads after the "populateLocationMap()" runs.

Comment: But how can you force any future developer who will be maintaining your code will do it in same way ?

Comment: If, by 'future developer', you are talking about a developer-who-has-access-to-your-code, the answer is clear ... there is nothing you can do.